# Unable to resolve controller parameter in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular application on my local machine, which works fine on local machine but doesnt work when promoted to Test Server.

My file structure is:

```
-- Controller
-- -- AController
-- -- BController

-- Views
-- -- Test
-- -- -- Index.html
-- -- -- Start.html
-- -- -- End.html
```

angular module config look like:

`.config(
   [
       '$routeProvider',
       function ($routeProvider)
       {

           $routeProvider
               .when('/',
               {
                   templateUrl: '/test/start',
                   controller: 'AController'
               })
               .when('/thank-you',
               {
                   templateUrl: '/test/end',
                   controller: 'AController',

               })

       }
   ])`

Initially when i promoted my code to Test server. I wasn't getting anything as i was promoting under a folder in test server. so i changed my `templateUrl's` values to `'subfolder/test/start'`, by changing this, i now get my form displayed (its going to main.html page)) but no server side data (like drop down data etc) on page load gets displayed.

Can someone please guide what i need to do to get this working, seems like some path issue where its unable to initialize controller or something.

Another question, Is there any simple way to sort out path issue? changing `templateUrl` everytime i promote my code seems meaningless.

Thanks for your help.

I am very new to angularJs and still learning :)

Comment: What errors are you getting?  For instance, if you look at Chrome/Firefox console, does it say something like "404 /start.html"?

Comment: i was getting that, but then i changed my ````templateUrl```` so i have started getting my html page but the serverside doesn't get hit as i am retrieving drop down data from server side on page load.

Comment: But i get 404 for all the server-side calls

Comment: Without seeing the code/layout this a difficult problem to troubleshoot.  If this is not a production app, you could put it up on Github.  Aside from that, I would suggest looking in Chrome Dev Tools > Network > XHR and determine if your http requests are going to the URL endpoints you expect, and if not adjust accordingly.  Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to use relative paths. in my apps I always prefix my paths with `../`.

for example:

```
.when('/', {
  templateUrl: '../test/start',
  controller: 'AController'
})
```

Comment: Ganonside: The problem is not the ````templateUrl````, its the ````controller````. either adding ````../```` or writing subfolder name only helps in displaying template but the controller (which is server side code) doesnt get called.